# Eclipse Maven Projects False Error

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I have a parent Maven project that consists of several other projects. When i am building the project in command line everything is fine.

Then i open my Eclipse and the workspace is full of errors (which are actually false positives).

In order for me to get rid of this errors i have to do a **"Run As... -> Maven install"** and then a **"Maven -> Update project..."** on every project from within eclipse.

Is there any way or any plugin that can actually refresh the workspace and update the maven dependencies on each project, so that i can avoid this tedious operation?

Does anyone else face the same problem when using Eclipse as an IDE for his/her maven projects?

**UPDATE**
It seems (as in most of the cases with eclipse) that the problem was with the **M2E plugin**. Somehow the plugin was picking some settings in the .metadata folder in my workspace. I deleted the contents of the folder, restarted eclipse, re imported everythings and now it seems to behave as expected.

Hopefully, in newer version Eclipse will support Maven in a proper manner.

Comment: As far as I know, for most 'external build tools', you need to run similar 'update/sync/refresh' commands in the IDE to ensure that the IDE project model is in a consistent state.

Comment: I have seen these errors as well, have you found the solution/hack yet ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi i found that the errors were due to corrupted .metadata folder. In your workspace folder you will found an Eclipse .metadata folder. I deleted it(you will loose your workspace preferences, but in my case i wouldn't mind) and restarted Eclipse. After that Maven was working fine again, picking up changes in the pom.xml file and re-creating the classpath every time i was changing something in the pom.xml. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that some of the files are just out of date.  When I get this I do a refresh of the affected projects and then clean the workspace (Project -> Clean...) cleaning all projects.

If the refresh and clean don't do the trick, then I'd suspect that your maven settings in Eclipse point to a different set of repositories than does the command line maven's settings.xml.  Go into the maven property page in Eclipse preferences and confirm that you're using the same settings.xml (re-select just to be sure).

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am doing all this. I am refreshing all the projects and i am cleaning my workspace. But still no luck. After that i had to do a maven install and update on each individual project.